# How to scroll a div automatically with button onClick

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Hi i am trying to create an image slider that can slide with a next/prev button.
I also have an array of data that will be map through.
So this is my code.

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'

import { ThirdContainer, SecondContainer, ButtonLeft, ButtonRight, ButtonTitle, Container, FirstRow, FirstTitle, SecondRow, SecondTitle, TitleContainer } from './FirstSectionStyled'

const FirstSection = ({bgData}) => {

 //functions
 const nextSLide = () =>{}
 const prevSlide = () =>{}

    return (
        <Container>
            <ButtonLeft onClick={prevSLide}/>
                <SecondContainer id="scroller">
                    {bgData.map((data,index) => (
                        <ThirdContainer key={data.id} backgroundImg = {data.backgroundImg}>
                            <FirstRow>
                                <TitleContainer>
                                    <FirstTitle>{data.firstTitle}</FirstTitle>
                                    <SecondTitle>{data.secondTitle}</SecondTitle>
                                    <ButtonTitle>Buy Now</ButtonTitle>
                                </TitleContainer>
                            </FirstRow>
                            <SecondRow>
                            </SecondRow>
                        </ThirdContainer>
                    ))
                    }
                </SecondContainer> 
            <ButtonRight onClick={nextSLide} />
        </Container>
    )
}

export default FirstSection
```

And this is the styled component

```
export const SecondContainer = styled.div`
    height:100%;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: auto;
    background: black;
    display : flex;

`
export const ThirdContainer = styled.div`
    min-width: 100vw;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 70% 30%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(21, 21, 21, 0.5), rgb(21, 21, 21, 0.2), rgb(21, 21, 21, 0.2), rgb(21, 21, 21, 0.4)), 
                      url(${(props) => (props.backgroundImg)});
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
`
```

The problem is How can I make the `SecondContainer` to scroll its x-axis by 100vw everytime the button is clicked so that it will show the next `ThirdContainer` and create the image slider effect. I also want to make it animate smoothly. So any idea to solve this? Thank u!

Comment: `element.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord)` use `scrollTo` function, 
read the element using `document.getByClassName(....)`

Comment: how can i make it scroll 100vw ? because it give an error when i insert 100 vw.

Comment: You cannot scroll to `vw` !. you need to find the width of the element using `element.innerWidth` and then scroll to that innerWidth value

Comment: can u please explain to me how to do that? How can i get the value of the screen width and use it for `scrollto` because i want it to be responsive. Sorry because I am still new to this.

Comment: Will post it in answer

Comment: Thank you and also I want to make the scroll to be smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class name to your container

`<ThirdContainer className='third-container' ....`

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'

import { ThirdContainer, SecondContainer, ButtonLeft, ButtonRight, ButtonTitle, Container, FirstRow, FirstTitle, SecondRow, SecondTitle, TitleContainer } from './FirstSectionStyled'

const FirstSection = ({bgData}) => {

 //functions
 const nextSLide = (index) =>{
   let ele = document. getElementsByClassName('third-container')[0] //replace 0 with current active slide index
    document.getElementByClassName('second-container').scrollTo(ele.offsetWidth)
 }
 const prevSlide = () =>{}

    return (
        <Container>
            <ButtonLeft onClick={prevSLide}/>
                <SecondContainer className="second-container" id="scroller">
                    {bgData.map((data,index) => (
                        <ThirdContainer className='third-container' key={data.id} backgroundImg = {data.backgroundImg}>
                            <FirstRow>
                                <TitleContainer>
                                    <FirstTitle>{data.firstTitle}</FirstTitle>
                                    <SecondTitle>{data.secondTitle}</SecondTitle>
                                    <ButtonTitle>Buy Now</ButtonTitle>
                                </TitleContainer>
                            </FirstRow>
                            <SecondRow>
                            </SecondRow>
                        </ThirdContainer>
                    ))
                    }
                </SecondContainer> 
            <ButtonRight onClick={nextSLide} />
        </Container>
    )
}

export default FirstSection
```

please note this is not tested in an actual environment. the method could help you to implement it. if it still not working please post your code to slackBits and share the link in comments